# Does every theorem in $\mathbb{C}^n$ hold for $K^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

There any many books that cover many of the topics in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$. There are many theorem in these topics. I know I cannot use $\mathbb{R}^n$ theorem on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and I think I can use $\mathbb{C}^n$ theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If I want to study a new vector space $K^n$ on field $K$ (for example $\mathbb{Q}^n$), can I use $\mathbb{C}^n$ theorem in $K^n$? If not, can I use all of the theorem in $\mathbb{C}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Pretty much any linear algebra question that is true for $\mathbb{C}^n$ is true for $K^n$ (since, as the answer below states, linear algebra depends only on the field properties of $\mathbb{C}^n$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason that a true theorem for $\mathbb C^n$ would be true for $K^n$.

For example, "$\mathbb C^n$ infinitely many elements" is obviously false for $K^n$ when $K$ is a finite field.

To continue on finite fields $K$, when $K$ has characteristic $2$, you don't have the equivalence between quadratic forms and bilinear forms, since you cannot divide by $2$.

Even in the case where $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$, you cannot apply all theorems you proved for $\mathbb C^n$ (or at least you should be very careful): for example, every endomorphism of $\mathbb C^n$ has an eigenvalue, but this is in general false for $K^n$.

What is true and useful is that most of the basic theorems you proved for $\mathbb C^n$ doesn't use the particular properties of $\mathbb C$ but only its field structure. In these case, the theorem apply to any field $K$.

Comment: The post edited.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really change the question. I changed my answer though, to fit the new wording of the question.